# ARKit – All fragments in a plane at the same Z-depth

Tags: scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, depth-buffer

In an ARKit scene I display a number of planes representing photos placed at various points. Sometimes the photos intersect with each other, which doesn't look so great.

To avoid this, I'd like to make the Z-depth every fragment / pixel of each image the same as its centre point. That way, if the centre of image `A` is in front of image `B`, then every pixel of `A` will be considered in front of `B`.

I know I could use a custom shader and set the depth buffer accordingly, but what I want to know is if there's an easier way with SceneKit framework to override how the depth buffer is written.